# ASP classic - Is it possible to force running clientside VBScript in 32bit?

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic

We have a Windows 2003 server **32bit** that host an ASP classic app. This application calls `CreateObject("CDO.Message")` to send an email. This code is located in a clientside `<script>` tag in the .asp page.

Everything works well when I access the page on a 32 bit OS. The problem is it does not work when executed on a 64 bit machine (ActiveX can't create object...). My guess is because it calls the 64bit VBScript thing, and because the server is 32 bit it can't work.

Is it possible to make code in the `<script>` tag run both on 32bit machine and 64bit machines? I would prefer not have to recode the application to put the email sending code serverside, if possible.

---

EDIT - More information about what it is doing: The app very old and worked well until we started migrating users from xp 32bit to win8 64bit recently. It is targeted at IE only.

Why the `CreateObject` is "client side" (I'm not even sure about that, but I can view the code in the source of the asp page when I'm in the browser) is because the email is sent on the click of a button, and the event handling code of that button is in the `<script>` tag. Why it was made like that I don't know.

Here's a sample of the script tag located in the `<HEAD>` block of the asp page:

```
<SCRIPT ID=clientEventHandlersVBS language=VBScript>
<!--
Sub btnEnvoyer_onclick
    dim objMail

    set objmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
End Sub
-->
</SCRIPT>
```

It crashes on `CreateObject` and stops there with the error:

> ActiceX can't create object

If I access it from a 32bit OS (win7 32bit for example, it works. That's why I think there's probably some sort of compatibility problem between the 32 bit server ans 64 bit clients).

Button that calls that sub :

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Envoyer" id=btnEnvoyer name=btnEnvoyer class=boutons>
```

Comment: Why are you creating `CDO.Message` client side??

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean it's located in a client-side `<script>` tag? Why is the client calling `Server.CreateObject()`? And are you only targeting IE clients? Can you post some code?

Comment: @Bond I edited my question to add more info, hope it's less confusing

Comment: Make more sense now. You have a typo in your first paragraph. You say it calls `Server.CreateObject()`, not `CreateObject()`.

Comment: Oops, I guess I confused both. It call CreateObject without the "Server" part. Corrected it

Comment: This should have nothing to do with ASP because it's the _client_ that's running the code. Have one of your 64-bit clients try to use the 32-bit version of IE (it's in the `Program Files (x86)` folder and see if it works.

Comment: @Lankymart asks a good question about using CDO client side.  For this to work then either an smtp server would need to be installed on the client machine, or an external smtp server, along with its address and login details would need to be specified in client side code - visible to everyone.  I suppose this could work in an office intranet, which is where you usually find client side VBS, but if the site is written in asp then it would make sense to move your cdo operation to the server side.

Comment: Tried IE 32 bits, but it dosen't work. @Lankymart It's indeed an intranet app, so it dosen't matter much if clients see the smtp password. But I started moving the code serverside to see if i can get it working. I noticed it's not only CDO the problem, it does that with almost every `CreateObject`. There's a `"Scripting.FileSystemObject"` later in the code used to attach a file, and it crash also on 64bits...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, afters hours of investigation, I found that it's in no way related to 32bit/64bit incompatibility, but there was one of the security options of the Intranet Zone ("Initialize and script activex controls not marked as safe") in Internet Explorer of the Windows 8 users that was preventing the application from executing ActiveX components.

I activated it and now everything is working fine.